# Pull Account Name from Message in Eventlog - powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to pull the `account name` from the message property in an event log.  For instance I am running the following command:

```
get-eventlog -computername dc-01 -logname security | ?{$_.eventid -eq "4674"} | convertto-html -property machinename,eventid,entrytype,message | out-file c:\test.html
```

I want to be able to pull the `account name` out of message but not necessary for specific users.  Ideally, it would create another column named `Account Name` which we could sort on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the second item of the ReplacementStrings property of each event. It contains the values embeded in the message.

```
get-eventlog -computername dc-01 -logname security | ?{$_.eventid -eq "4674"} | 
select machinename,eventid,@{n='AccountName';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[1]}},entrytype,message | 
convertto-html | out-file c:\test.html
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  I forgot about the `select-object` cmdlet

Comment: And this for Get-Winevent

`Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1|select -Property @{n='AccountName';e={$($_.userid).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}`